# Запрет отправки изменений на сервер TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Есть группа разработчиков из нескольких человек. В эту группу входит одни-два человека, которым необходимо запретить прямую отправку ожидающих изменений (<kbd>Pending Changes</kbd>) кода на сервер через <kbd>Check In</kbd>, а сделать так, чтобы создавался <kbd>Rewiew Code</kbd> на выбранного программиста из группы (либо на одного определенного, без выбора). Суть в том, что есть программисты, которые пишут не очень хороший код, который в результате приходится переписывать. Понимаю, что вопрос: *"Зачем нужны такие программисты?"* здесь уместен, но увы, я с этим ничего поделать не могу. Необходимо проверять, хотя бы бегло, изменения этих программистов. Схема взаимодействия в два шага:

1. Программист из группы вносит изменения
2. Если права есть - отправляет изменения на сервер, если нет - отправляет изменения на проверку другому программисту, который только после утверждения может их отправить на сервер

Возможно ли реализовать такую настройку в **Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2015**?